# Cannot read property 0 of undefined in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So I know that this question has been asked a few times but I can't seem to find a solution for my case. I am using a v-for to loop through an array of objects however I am also accessing data for the nested array of each object.

Note* originally I was using the original data `getter` to loop through but I switched to computed to see if it would make a difference to no success as of yet

here is the `v-for`

```
<tbody class="client-info table-bordered">
   <tr v-for="(user, index) in computedUsers"  :key="index" v-if="users.length > 0">
   <td class="text-capitalize">{{ user.user }}</td>
   <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
   <td>{{ user.role.name }}</td>// My issue is at this line
   <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Edit</button></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

and here is the computed property

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['users']),
     computedUsers() {
       if(this.users.length > 0 ) {
          const index = 0
            return this.users.map((user) =>({user: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.roles[index]}))
       }  
    }
  },
```

**Now there is no issue If i simply load the page, however if I commit a mutation that adds a new object to the array, I get the alarm that `cannot read property 0 of undefined`.** any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question. When you initially load the page,  `users.length` is `0`, causing the following line not to run. Once you add (commit) a new user, it's trying to find `users.roles[index]`, where `index` is hardcoded to `0` for some reason. That's your error. `user.roles` isn't a proper array.

Comment: My guess is that after the mutation it breaks on one of the user records that does not have the `role` property in it, hence the `cannot read property 0 of undefined`. Make sure each of your new users have the `role` property and better yet it actually has at least one role assigned to it.

Comment: My issue was the `response.data` I was using to to mutate the arrray of `users` was not including the `roles` array. So I actually had to fix my back end code. Thank you for the help

Comment: You should answer your question if you found the solution to your problem so that if someone else finds this page they'll get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I needed to include the nested array of data on my `return response`.

When it would run the `v-for` with out the included `roles` array it would obviously not exist because my return response was only sending the `user` object.

So for those familiar with Laravel I changed

```
return response($user, 200);
```

To this

```
return response($user->load('roles'), 200);
```